# Replacing html tag with null in XML string

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I want to replace `<![CDATA[` tag in xml string with null but I don't know how to find or grab this tag using regular expression in swift 2.0

My xml string is something like :

```
let xmlvar = "<description>" +
            "<![CDATA[<img data-toggle='tooltip' src='uploads/posts/thumbnails/92-9-6-khatami-5-52-on.jpg' alt='123'/><span>123</span>]]>" +
            "</description>
```

which I need to remove `<![CDATA[` and it's end part `]]` from xmlvar

Update :

how can I use Regular expression on xml data from rss feed ? 
I'm facing `xml is not convertible to NSString` error

here is my code :

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://razavitv.aqr.ir/index/rss/2") 
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in               
    let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
    let processedString = (xml as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<![CDATA[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]]", withString: "") as String                
    let appName = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["title"].element!.text!
    let appUrl = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["description"]["img"].element!.attributes["src"]
    let ap = Apps(name: appName , img : appUrl)
    self.tableData.append(ap)
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
}
task.resume()
```

Any suggestion how ?

Comment: Do you also want to remove the content between `<![CDATA[` and `]]`, or just these two parts? Better if you also add to the question the result you want to obtain.

Comment: @Cristik  i need the content in between.

Comment: A CDATA section ends with `]]>`, not just `]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSString`'s `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` functionality:

```
let processedString = (xmlvar as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<![CDATA[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]]", withString: "") as String
```

You convert to `NSString`, apply the two replacements, and then get back to `String`

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
// we know for sure the regex is a valid string, thus the forced try, otherwise forced stuff is not recommended
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\<\\!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
let len = xmlvar.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSStringEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
let processedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(xmlvar, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, len), withTemplate: "")
print(processedString)
```

Comment: Thanks worked like charm. but I have another problem that i can not do that on xml data from rss feed. i updated the post above. do you have any suggestion how to accomplish this?

Comment: This new problem deserves another question, as it's a different topic, but I'll answer it anyway: `xml` in an object, not a string. You need to apply the transformation to the actual strings that you work with: `appName`, or `appUrl`

Comment: Or, you can convert `data` to a `String`, apply the transformation, then convert back to `NSData` before sending it to `parse`.

Comment: Thank you. worked like charm. I've converted data to string and i've done string replacing on it and then i convert it back to NSDATA and it work.

Comment: Hi , I faced a bug in this conversion! when I first get the xml and put it into data when I get the count of it's item I get 388. but when I do the string replacing on it I get 182 item. do you have any idea why ! and how to fix it?

Comment: Without the code and the actual data is hard to tell what's happening. Do a little debugging and you'll find out what text disappears and what line of code produces this behaviour.

Comment: I found out which line makes this bug :  let processedString = (dataString as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<![CDATA[", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]]", withString: "") as String

Comment: the conversion is not effecting the count of items but replacing the strings is reducing the items, i'm putting the full code for you to understand it better.

Comment: This is not the way SO works: you keep updating the questing every time you run into another problem. Please do some debugging, identify the problematic piece of code, and you you cannot figure out what the problem is, ask another question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. but I debugged the code and then I updated the above code.